# Where are saved my notes mediawiki?

Tags: php, wiki, mediawiki

I'm searching for my notes on my old mediawiki that I've saved. How can I see it and how can I put it in my new wiki? I read that it doesn't use any BDD, so I expect that they are savec into the files that I've backuped!

Thanks to help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MediaWiki *does* use a database. The best thing to do would be to look into your MediaWiki configuration file to figure out which DB it was using. It's possible it was a SQLite DB, in which case you'll find the path to the DB file.

Comment: apparently, includes/DefaultSettings.php contains the sql settings

Comment: DefaultSettings.php is supposed to contain the *default* settings. Your specific settings should be in LocalSettings.php.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are talking about this [notes-pugin](http://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3anote).
If you migrate to a new Dokuwiki, you have to make sure that the plugin is installed. If you still cannot see your notes, make sure that you use the default templates.